# Cosa significa "tenda" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *L'isola*, di Giani Stuparich, ho letto:

> Poi il suo sguardo confuso venne attratto da qualche cosa di candido alla riva, sotto la casa. Una barchetta gialla con la **tenda** bianchissima ondeggiava a ogni più lieve movimento del barcaiolo, che, seduto sulla prora, la teneva a riva presso i gradini.

Non sono sicura di cogliere il senso della parola "tenda" in questo passaggio. Si tratta della vela della barchetta menzionata nel testo? Oppure il significato è questo, che ho trovato nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tenda) (che infatti non riesco a capire bene cosa sia)?

> Nell’allestimento navale, riparo di tela olona, sostenuto con draglie a robusti candelieri e tesato con cavi, disposto in semplice o doppio ordine, a protezione dei ponti scoperti e delle murate delle navi contro il sole e la pioggia.

Comment: Sì, si riferisce chiaramente alla vela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato è proprio quello che hai trovato tu per [tenda](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tenda/):

> **c.** Nell'allestimento navale, riparo di tela olona, sostenuto con
>   draglie a robusti candelieri e tesato con cavi, disposto in semplice o
>   doppio ordine, a protezione dei ponti scoperti e delle murate delle
>   navi contro il sole e la pioggia. Ponte tenda, nella costruzione
>   navale, sovrastruttura leggera, costituita da un ponte sostenuto
>   semplicemente da montanti e puntelli; navi a ponte t., le navi munite
>   di un ponte di questo genere, usate nei traffici dei passeggeri per
>   viaggi di breve durata, o in mari tropicali.

La tela olona è una tela molto più spessa della normale vela e viene usata come protezione del ponte dal sole e dalle intemperie; infatti quelle moderne possono essere anche impermeabili.

Le draglie sono i cavi tesati tra i candelieri delle barche posti per evitare la caduta accidentale fuori bordo.